# Is There a notion of Convergence for the Non-Standard Reals? How can we do Analysis?

Tags: soft-question, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

I was reading up on Non-Standard Analysis from an Analytical perspective,
i.e., how to do Analysis when I got stuck thinking of how we can do Analysis without even having a "traditional" metric , e.g., if $x$ is a(n) non-real infinitesimal then $d(x,0)=x$ is non-Real, which is not allowed in traditional metrics. But then if the topology is not metrizable, just how is it given? I am curious because I am having trouble thinking of notions of convergence. How about " Physical/Geometrical" models for the Non-Standard Reals in the sense of the Real line being a model for the axioms for the standard Reals? Sorry, I am trying to clarify my thoughts here (Clearly without much success so far ). In my basic research I found that the minimal conditions to be able to do Analysis in a Topological space X is that X must be a Topological Field where 0 is a limit point of $X-\{0\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Right, I guess I didn't ask clearly. Since the topology is not one given by a metric, what is the topology used?

Comment: Actually, it's better to not even talk about topology at all. The usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of convergence doesn't talk about metrics at all - just absolute value, subtraction, and inequalities. All of that makes sense in the hyperreals too, so exactly the same definition works there.

Comment: So we use elementary equivalence to justify being able to do this or is it more basic? Thanks, but I would also like to know if it is possible to talk about convergence or if there is some topology defined in the Hyperreals.

Comment: Sorry, are you asking about convergence of sequences or limits of functions? The latter is a bit easier to think about at first.

Comment: Incidentally, while there are multiple topologies of interest on the hyperreals, the simplest one for your purposes here is just the one with base consisting of all open intervals.

Comment: Another passive-aggressive downvoting member. Bet they don't even understand the question. If you respond by downvoting other answers, I will report you. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this is the kind of answer that you wanted or expected.

You only need a topology to talk about convergence in general. To get a nice and convenient topology on non-standard sets ${^*}Y$, one usually takes superstructures (actually in a way such that ${^*}Y$ is an enlargement) and defines any union of sets from ${^*}\tau$ as open, where $\tau$ is a topology on the set $Y$.

What you do in non-standard analysis (instead of non-standard topology) is rather to reformulate analytical notions like convergence in terms of other notions. For example we have that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = b$$ if and only if  $\text{st}(a_N) = b$ for all $N \in 
   {^*}\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N}$, where "$\text{st}$" denotes taking the standard part.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of convergence:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, if $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$ then $\vert f(x)-L\vert<\epsilon$.

This makes perfect sense in the hyperreals, without changing anything: just make sure that all the variables are allowed to range over the hyperreals. So, for example, to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}x=c$, we just set $\delta=\epsilon$ as usual.

Note that this definition applies to *any* function ${}^*\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{}^*\mathbb{R}$. Of course, we're usually really interested in the ones which come from functions on $\mathbb{R}$; given such an $f$, in the nonstandard setting we replace $f$ with ${}^*f$ and go as above. We can then use the transfer property to show that everything we're going to get in this context is actually true in standard analysis too.

Similarly, to tell whether a sequence $X=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ from the standard world converges to some standard real $L$, we first pass to its nonstandard version ${}^*X=({}^*x_n)_{n\in{}^*\mathbb{N}}$ and then ask, in the hyperreal world, the usual question: is it the case that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $n$ such that for all $m>n$ we have $\vert {}^*x_m-L\vert<\epsilon$? Transfer tells us (as usual) that this gives the desired result.

Comment: I note in a lot of the textbook arguments discussing this it seems like $$\epsilon>0$$ or alternatively put $$\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$$, and similairly with the $$n\in \mathbb{N}$$ isn't transferred at all and some point is made about some elements being standard while other aren't, how does this fit with the clean idea of transferring everything?

Comment: @East: Only 1st order properties are transferred. Maybe that property you mention is a 2nd order property or higher.

Comment: @Noah Schweber. Sorry, Noah, both answers were good, can only accept one.